# determine if clang-format finds .clang-format file (in a shell or cmake script)

Tags: cmake, clang-format

### what i want to achieve

I want to pack a `.clang-format` file with my software, which only gets used if the user doesn't provide their own.

My idea so far is to use `clang-format -style=file` which will find the users `.clang-format` if it is ["located in one of the parent directories of the source file"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). (Which might be the case because it is in their home directory, or because they are using my package as a git submodule, or because they manually placed it after downloading my software).

If no `.clang-format` file is found, then the one shipped with my software should be used - e.g. by symlinking to `mypackage/auxiliary_files/.clang-format` in the top level. I want to do this somewhat automatized from cmake directly or by calling a shell script from cmake (or other).

#### workflow in short

`clang-format` finds `.clang-format`: do nothing (as shell script `exit 0`; as cmake script `set(I-FOUND-CLANG-FORMAT 1)` or something similar)

`clang-format` doesn't find `.clang-format`: call `ln -s auxiliary_files/.clang-format`

#### what I don't want to do

I don't want to write a loop which replicates the search behaviour of `clang-format` (going one directory up to look for `.clang-format` until either it's found or the top most directory is reached) to have built-in 100% compatibility.

#### options i've seen but didn't figure out how to use for my goal

`clang-format` does not appear to return a non-zero status code if no style file has been provided although `style=file` is set, even if `-fallback-style=none` is set. I also don't see in the printout if the fallback option or the regular option is used.

Comment: drafted it as patch for clang-format: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/pull/21 to be discussed with the developers.

Comment: The option `-fallback-style=fail` is accepted in https://reviews.llvm.org/D30742